# Why use json_agg filter clause in postgresql not working?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I write a sql to calculate retention data in **PostgreSQL 11.3 **,

```
SELECT
    part_date,
    platid,
    json_agg(json_build_array(return_gap, users)) filter (where return_gap is null)  as return_retention_values
FROM (
SELECT
    part_date,
    platid,
    json_agg(json_build_array(return_gap, users)) filter (
        where
            return_gap is null
    ) as return_retention_values
FROM
    (
        select
            part_date,
            platid,
            return_gap,
            users
        from
            my_table
    ) a
GROUP BY
    grouping sets (
        (part_date, platid, return_gap),
        (part_date, platid)
    )
) a
group by
    part_date,
    platid
order by
    part_date asc
```

its return result like:

```
part_date   platid  return_retention_values
2022-11-08  23  [[3, 345], [6, 248], [2, 408], [5, 286], [null, 1], [null, 1532], [1, 535], [4, 323], [7, 199], [0, 1531]]
2022-11-08  2   [[7, 902], [null, 5379], [5, 1382], [6, 1258], [3, 1666], [1, 2680], [0, 5379], [4, 1486], [2, 1961]]
2022-11-08  1   [[1, 1042], [7, 388], [4, 600], [3, 1600], [null, 3171], [2, 716], [0, 3171], [5, 1524], [6, 1485]]
2022-11-09  1   [[5, 1597], [0, 3086], [4, 1641], [2, 1767], [3, 578], [null, 1], [null, 3087], [1, 963], [6, 366]]
```

the  **(where return_gap is null)** seems not working, **null** values still in query result, how to fix it?

Comment: It would be easier to work with this if you provided sample input data we could run your query against. For now, it looks like you wanted `filter (where return_gap is NOT null` but specified the opposite. Also, initially you attached a bit different query (above formatting) and after edit, left the output unchanged.

Comment: You can think of `filter` meaning *"apply a filter to keep only these"* in regards to what comes after `where` clause in the parentheses, as opposed to *"filter these out"* that you seem to assume now.

Comment: 11.3 is very old.  The current bug fix is 11.18.